# PrimeNG time picker won't allow me to change the time

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG for its calendar functions, but I'm trying to get the time picker to work as it won't allow me to change the time. Here's the code I have for it in my template:

```
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">
    <h3>Time Only </h3>
    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date8" [timeOnly]="true"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

What I see is this:

[image]

As you can see, it won't allow me to change the time because the arrows don't show up as they do in the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the Font-Awesome requirement, which would give you the icons you need.

you will need to run `npm install font-awesome --save` in your project folder, and then be sure to add the styles section of your `angularcli.json` file (this information is available in the `Get Started` section of the PrimeNg site.

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
  //...
],
```